# execute different codes in code behind on confirm ok and cancel using textbox methods and property only

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

This is the script and I want to use it in code behind previously I used clentclick property of button button I want to use this code without using button

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
     function Confirm() {
         var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
         confirm_value.type = "hidden";
         confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
         if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
             confirm_value.value = "Yes";
         } else {
             confirm_value.value = "No";
         }
         document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
     }
    </script>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

what else can I do so that it is achievable for me

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // TextBox1.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "Confirm()");
        string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
        if (confirmValue == "Yes")
        {
            //Your logic for OK button
        }
        else
        {
            //Your logic for cancel button
        }
    }
 public void OnConfirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: What is the equivalent of onclientclick in textbox, without calling js code will not run

Comment: textboxes do not have a click event they are not designed to be buttons. You will need some way to submit the form back to the server either through JavaScript or via a button. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Leave a button on the page, hide it using css and then call click() from JavaScript after you have set your value:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        document.getElementById("Button1").click();
    }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onchange="Confirm()"></asp:TextBox>
<div style="display:none;"><asp:Button ID="Button1" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Clicked" /></div>
```

Then in your codebehind:

```
protected void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
    if (confirmValue == "Yes")
    {
        //Your logic for OK button
    }
    else
    {
        //Your logic for cancel button
    }
}
```

Comment: But the confirm message is not triggered on text_changed event

Comment: My bad, the `onclientchanged` should infact have been the JS onchange event